# Magento include products sku in orders CSV

Tags: magento, export-to-csv, orders

The default orders export CSV file does not contain sku of the products. Is there any way i can include sku of the products in an order.

Any help will be highly appropriated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first add SKU column in order grid and then you can use export CSV to get that column in exported file.

To add SKU column, follow below article.

http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-sku-column-to-orders-grid/

Comment: Thanks @Emipro Technologies your guide me in the right directions